# passing parameters to get function within FOSRestBundle

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

To be short, when accessing a **GET** action something like offset/limit will also need to be concluded. I'm wandering how to set parameters for this?

Like this:

```
public function getThreadsAction($userKey, $offset, $limit)
{ #logic here
  ......
}
```

Or using ParameterFetcherInterface:

```
public function getThreadsAction($userKey, ParameterFetcherInterface $fetcher)
{ #logic here
  $offset = $fetcher->get('offset');
  ......
}
```

Or using Request directly:

```
public function getThreadsAction($userKey, Request $request)
{ #logic here
  $offset = $request->get('offset');
  ......
}
```

Temporarily if it's like the first one, the route looks like `/api/threads/{userKey}.{_format}`.
 Do I need to set a `@GET()`annotation? Otherwise if it goes in the other ways is it necessary to set a `@QueryParam` for `limit` & `offset`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I always use query params for limit, offset, search (and other filters) for similar stuff. So you can access it like this:

```
$request->query->get('limit')
```

Also it would be nice to set default limit value in config, so if client doesn't send value for limit you will use the one from config.